# How to generate massive dataset from directory of hundreds of .csv's with unique labels to columns [R]?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to try and do the following:

1. I have a folder with hundreds of .csv's, each of which only need to be extracted and analyzed in R for their first column - they are relative intensities of cells.
2. I would like for a script to
   **a) loop through the directory, b) extract and import each .csv as a data frame or vector, c) label each with an ascending labeling system, and d) re-combine them for a comprehensive data set for further analysis (*each data frame represents a different cell treatment)***

**Here's some code since I get shredded with downvotes for not doing this otherwise:**

```
#data are sort of structured like this, as relative intensities of a cell from an image:
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- sample(100:1000, 100, replace = T)  
df2 <- sample(100:1000, 100, replace = T)
df3 <- sample(100:1000, 100, replace = T)
df4 <- sample(100:1000, 100, replace = T)
df5 <- sample(100:1000, 100, replace = T)
```

```
#this will be the subfolder where all the .csvs are located, not as it is here:
my_direct <- "~./"

#this will be the list of files:
my_files <- list.files(path=my_direct, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

#this should retrieve over 100 .csv files, all with just one column needed for further analysis:

#then I wanted to do this....
dfs <- lapply(myfiles, read.delim)
```

```
#but that just generates an amorphous blob of a list -
#I need each belonging to it's own column, labeled differently, so that I can cbind to generate a massive dataset

#so I tried this:
map(my_files, fread, select = 'Intensity Sum Ch=3 Img=1') %>%
  bind_cols

#and it produced similar results or collapses the data
```

I feel like it's right in front of me (doing some sort of for loop magic) but I can't seem to find the solution on here either.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `lapply`

```
#this will be the subfolder where all the .csvs are located, not as it is here:
my_direct <- "~./"

#this will be the list of files:
my_files <- list.files(path=my_direct, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

# read each file in list
data_list = lapply(my_files, function(i){
  data <- read.csv(i, stringsAsFactors = F)
# Make changes to data as required
})

# merge all elements of list into data.table
data_dt <- setDT(
  unlist(data_list, recursive = FALSE),
  check.names = TRUE
)[]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But wouldn't I use ```cbind``` and not ```rbind```? I need unique columns, because what happens is that the data are read in, but then mushed on top of each other and I have no clue where each came from. They need to be stored as unique columns.

Comment: Do accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: It still does not run for me. I get the following error: ```error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names```